# Angular 5 input array from other component , cause length 0

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

I put the collected data from services into the array. I put this array through @Input into the second component but in it the array instead of length 18 has 0;

TS:

```
  arr: Datas[] = [];


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ng init");
    this.getArraysFromData();

  }

  getArraysFromData() {
    this.DataService.getDatas().subscribe((data: Datas[]) => {
      for (let item of data) {
        this.arr.push(item);
      }
      console.log("smartlamps from Map ", this.arr);
    });
  }
```

}

HTML :

```
<app-osm-generator [dataInput]="arr"></app-osm-generator>
```

COMPONENT WHERE I INPUT

```
@Input() dataInput: Datas[];


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.takeDataFromInput();
}

takeDataFromInput() {
console.log(this.dataInput.length);   <-- is 0 must be 18
  for(let item of dataInput) { 
    console.log(item); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(this.dataInput.length)` and `for(let item of this.dataInput)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `console.log(dataInput.length);` coz its is being called before data is assigned

There are 2 ways you can solve the issue :

**1) Include `app-osm-generator` only when data is available**

```
<app-osm-generator *ngIf="arr.length > 0" [dataInput]="arr"></app-osm-generator>
```

**2) `implements OnChanges`**

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    let data = changes.dataInput;
    console.log('prev value: ', data.previousValue);
    console.log('got name: ', data.currentValue);
    console.log(data.length);
}
```

Checking console will clear all your doubts regarding the flow

For more details on 2nd method : **[READ](https://ngdev.space/angular-2-input-property-changes-detection-3ccbf7e366d2)**

---

**Suggestion :**

```
this.DataService.getDatas().subscribe((data: Datas[]) => {
    this.arr = [ ...this.arr , ...data]; // instead of looping try out ES6's feature 
    console.log("smartlamps from Map ", this.arr);
});
```

Comment: @Blackboy , checkout the suggestion in answer also , might help you , Happy Coding BTW :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if is a mistake in the question but not this.DataService because DataService is the Service declaration and dataService is the instance injected..

```
this.DataService.getDatas().subscribe((data: Datas[]) => {
      for (let item of data) {
        this.arr.push(item);
      }
      console.log("smartlamps from Map ", this.item);
```

Good:

```
this.dataService.getDatas().subscribe((data: Datas[]) => { // good!
      for (let item of data) {
        this.arr.push(item);
      }
      console.log("smartlamps from Map ", this.item);
```

Comment: Yours code is good i make a mistake when i copy my code on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ because DataService is the Service declaration and dataService is the instance injected

Comment: @RubénSoler Thanks, I saw that. But the explanation is useful at least for the OP and for other users. So, you can put it in your answer by using edit link. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

add a **`ngIf`**

```
<app-osm-generator *ngIf="arr" [dataInput]="arr"></app-osm-generator>
```